# how to center the image of a radio button?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I want to center the image that has the radio button as follows.

[image]

I am using this code.

```
    <RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:drawableTop="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:gravity="bottom|right" />
     <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:drawableTop="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:gravity="bottom|right" />
    </RadioGroup>
```

Comment: I edited my answer and now there is `Layout` like in Your question. Check it

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true" />


    </LinearLayout>


</RadioGroup>
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: thanks for replying, I have verified the mentioned code but the functionality of the radiogroup is lost.